# BigQuery Not Pulling in LocationUserLocationStats from Google Ads transfer

Tags: google-bigquery

According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/google-ads-transformation), when I transfer my data from Google Ads to BigQuery one of the tables that is supposed to be created is called LocationUserLocationsStats. However, this table is not showing up for me in BQ after my transfer. I'm looking for location_view metrics and the documentation says that's where I'd find it. Any reason this table would not be created on my transfer?

Thanks!